# Scala : how to sample with iterator

Tags: scala

> Exercise: sample a 100 faces from the model and trace the position of point with id 610 in each sample.

**my answer**

```
val pc610 :IndexedSeq[Point[_3D]] =(0 until 100).map(pc610(i) => faceModel.sample.point(PointId(610)))
```

I am trying to take a practice on how to deal with sclasimo provided by CG group of Basel Univ.

This program handled by `scala` language and I'd like to act upon given Exercise request, but my trial returns error like following:

```
<console>:2: error: not a legal formal parameter.
Note: Tuples cannot be directly destructured in method or function parameters.
      Either create a single parameter accepting the Tuple1,
      or consider a pattern matching anonymous function: `{ case (param1, param1) => ... }
val pc610 :IndexedSeq[Point[_3D]] =(0 until 100).map(pc610(i) => faceModel.sample.point(PointId(610)))
```

Which code part might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your `map` call is not legal, it should look more like this

```
(0 until 100).map(i => <code using i>)
```

If you don't need the value of `i` you can just use the placeholder `_`, so perhaps this is what you need:

```
(0 until 100).map(_ => faceModel.sample.point(PointId(610)))
```